# Rails before action syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

```
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], :classify_article, only: [:create]
```

Why am i getting a syntax error here, it happened after after i added the classify_article function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a separate line for each before action:

```
before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :classify_article, only: [:create]
```